# Android Location info withought onLocationChanged

Tags: android, location

I'm writing a simple service that listens for Location changes.
In my onStart method I have the following

```
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Then how the service reacts to the changes is handled in the onLocationChanged(Location loc) method.

However I want to get the initial location when the service starts. Suppose there hasn't been any changes in the location info, I'd like to use location info at least once when the service starts, even if the location hasn't changed. How to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getLastKnownLocation` here.

Following snippet will help you.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)act.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(crit, true);
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did but then loc equals NULL.

Comment: are you trying this on emulator or device? You must have a valid GPS location, so, if the GPS is not enabled and you dont't have enough signal, the Location object will be ALWAYS null.

Comment: I'm using the emulator. It doesn't get a default location when in starts, does it?

Comment: That's the issue.You can emulate Lat & Lon through Emulator Control

Comment: Yes I can control them. But the emulator doesn't get a default location before I change anything?

Comment: Since Emulator have no GPS Hardware inside it.It can not get default location.

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer you should Accept it as it will help others.Thanks